# How to get the last update time of a table in mysql of version 8.0.21

Tags: mysql

My MySQL version is 8.0.21 and I want to use

```sql
select update_time from information_schema.tables where table_name='mytab' and table_schema='mydb'
```

to get the last update time but the result is `null`.

According to docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html), **change buffering** can delay the write to the data file. So I set the global variable **change buffering** to be 'null', which means [do not buffer any operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-change-buffer.html). But the result still empty.

Comment: Just store a time stamp in the table itself

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations to this, especially using the `InnoDB` engine. Take a look at the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html

They say:

**Update_time**

When the data file was last updated. For some storage engines, this value is NULL. For example, InnoDB stores multiple tables in its system tablespace and the data file timestamp does not apply. Even with file-per-table mode with each InnoDB table in a separate .ibd file, change buffering can delay the write to the data file, so the file modification time is different from the time of the last insert, update, or delete. For MyISAM, the data file timestamp is used; however, on Windows the timestamp is not updated by updates, so the value is inaccurate.

Update_time displays a timestamp value for the last UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE performed on InnoDB tables that are not partitioned. For MVCC, the timestamp value reflects the COMMIT time, which is considered the last update time. Timestamps are not persisted when the server is restarted or when the table is evicted from the InnoDB data dictionary cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is there a way that I could get the last update time?

Comment: Did you check the engine on your table? If it's ```InnoDB``` are you able to switch to ```MyISAM```?

Comment: The default engine is `InnoDB` and I have switched it to `MyISAM`, but the above statement still not work. Should I restart MySQL server?

Comment: @S.Carven are you aware above advantages and disadvantages of Innodb or MyISAM.  which engine suits for your requirement. and you can check last update time on OS level if per file is enabled.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA I don't know much about `InnoDB` or `MyISAM` in fact. Did you mean that I could check the file in disk, which stands for a table if the engine is `MyISAM`, to get the last update time?

Comment: Please find link which'll help you to get basics difference on both engines. Another, If you are using innodb engine and innodb per file enable then you'll find tablename.ibd file under datadirectory So whenever any change will happen on table those file will update..means checksum and all. If you use MyISAM then you'll find tablename.MYI  & tablename.MYD which will get change.

Answer (score 0):

It controlled by the variable information_schema_stats_expiry, by default it would be updated every 86400 secs (= 1 day) , so you can run "set information_schema_stats_expiry=1;" to let update_time updated in time.

BTW, I also checked the source code for both 8.0.21 and 5.7.30 ,and find there is a big difference between them for calculating the update_time of table, that is for 8.0 if information_schema_stats_expiry is larger than the diff between now -update_time of the table, then it would return the old update_time of the table, else it would return the real update_time of the table. below is the details:

For 8.0.21

```
 ulonglong Table_statistics::read_stat(
...........
 // Try to return the old update time of the table 
 if (!is_persistent_statistics_expired(thd, cached_timestamp)) {
 return table_stat_data;
 }
........

// Try to get new update time of the table 
if (!partition_name && hton_implements_get_statistics)
result = read_stat_from_SE(..........);
}
```

============================================================

For 5.7
the update_time would be keep on null until you update the table by the update statement sql such as  "update sync_test set c1= xxxx where id=yyyy";

from the source code perspective, UPDATE_TIME would be updated its value in real-time ,below is the detail:

step1,
When update the table the update_time would be assign to time "now" by  "(*it)->update_time = now;"

```
trx_update_mod_tables_timestamp(
/*============================*/
....................
for (trx_mod_tables_t::const_iterator it = trx->mod_tables.begin();
     it != end;
     ++it) {

    ............
    (*it)->update_time = now;
}
```

}

step2,  when running  select * from information_schema.tables , it invoked ha_innobase::info_low by the following method ,so time "now" assign to  stats.update_time

```
int
ha_innobase::info_low(
/*==================*/
uint    flag,   /*!< in: what information is requested */
bool    is_analyze)
{
   ................

    stats.update_time = (ulong) ib_table->update_time;
}
```

step3,  then  stats.update_time  assgin to [update_time](https://github.com/percona/percona-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_show.cc) of the table information_schema.tables.

```
 static int get_schema_tables_record(THD *thd, TABLE_LIST *tables,
                TABLE *table, bool res,
                LEX_STRING *db_name,
                LEX_STRING *table_name)
{
...........
  if (file->stats.update_time)
  {
    thd->variables.time_zone->gmt_sec_to_TIME(&time,
                                              (my_time_t) file->stats.update_time);
    table->field[15]->store_time(&time);
    table->field[15]->set_notnull();
  }
```

}

so  field UPDATE_TIME would be updated its value in real-time.

Comment: 感谢您详细的回答，然而在我的MySQL上，这个字段似乎失效了，我对目标表进行了插入、更新、删除等操作，`update_time`这个字段始终是NULL。我更想知道的是，如何能够获取到目标表的最后更新时间。

Comment: just by update_time from information_schema.tables to get the latest  update time , it works in my MySQL instance ,maybe you MySQL instance  corrupted?  How about test it at another MySQL instance?

Comment: In another 5.7.30 version MySQL, it woks; while my instance is 8.0.21.

Comment: percona or offical  version?

Comment: official verison

Comment: it control by the variable  information_schema_stats_expiry, you can run "set information_schema_stats_expiry=1"; to update in time.